# Enable LDAP on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ldap, yaml

So I'm trying to use LDAP authentication to connect to our institution from an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment running PHP 7.1.

I haven't been able to find much about this topic on the internet, other than one post on their forum that had no answers. However, from looking around, it seems like the best course of action would be to use a .ebextensions/.config file to enable the PHP LDAP extension in my environment.

Here is my current file configuration:

*/.ebextensions/phpini.config*

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension = php_ldap.dll
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be affecting anything. So is enabling LDAP on an AWS EB environment even an option here? If so, what would I have to modify in order to enable this?

Thanks in advance for any help and feel free to let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: Is the LDAP extension installed on your server? You may need to add a command to install the extension which should auto enable it within your PHP configuration.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that really. Now that I look at it though, the server is running Linux and I think it's only included by default in Windows. I'll try adding a command in the config to install php-ldap and update if it works or not.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking [Aaron W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138383/aaron-w)'s idea to install the extension as well as enabling it in the .config file and it ended up resolving my issue.

Here is the final script that I used in my Elastic Beanstalk environment to enable PHP LDAP.

```
commands:
  install_phpldap:
    command:
      sudo yum -y install php71-ldap

files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=php_ldap.dll
```

If anyone has any suggestions to improve upon this script, feel free to comment or provide a different answer and I will modify this answer (or change the accepted answer if it fits).